# PHP pack with multiple values with different lengths

Tags: php, bit, pack

I'd like to pack a string consisting of a 64 bits, 32 bits and 32 bits ints.
I don't have much experience with the pack function (or bits altogether) so I'm trying to do something like this:

```php
pack('JNN', 1, 2, 3);
// and
unpack('JNN');
```

But that does not yield the result I'm after.

The problem is that when I run that code I receive the following:

```
array [
  "NN" => 1
]
```

But I expected this:

```
array [
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

Any idea how to approach this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the result you are after?

Comment: @GetSet A way to pack and unpack a string or int consisting of 64bits, 32bits and 32bits. I’m using it to generate an ID for my application.

Comment: So you want a 64+32+32 = 128bit? Or do you want 64bits total made from two 32 bit longs?

Comment: @GetSet 128 bits :)

Comment: You seem to be on the right track then. `unpack()` returns an array of the "packed" string, containing the original values (e.g. 1, 2, 3). See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Comment: @GetSet Thanks but no. I've updated my question. Maybe it's more clear now what I expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pack creates a 16-character string.

```
$str = pack('JNN', 1, 2, 3);
//string(16) "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03"
```

unpack requires keys for the format elements. Example:

```
$arr = unpack('Jint64/N2int32_',$str);
/*
array (
  'int64' => 1,
  'int32_1' => 2,
  'int32_2' => 3,
)
*/
```

For more examples, see [Unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) in the PHP manual.

If purely numeric keys are required, the [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values) function can be used.